# Subir proyecto laravel 5.6 a Hosting

Tags: laravel, hosting

Ya termine mi proyecto laravel en su version 5.6 y necesito subirlo a hosting para implementarlo, alguna forma, ya intente con lo que hay en la web, pero no me funciona, lo subi, modifique el archivo index.php, el archivo .env... ¿habrá algo más que hacer?... se instala el laravel... entiendan que soy novato en esto... lo ultimo es que quiero subirlo a un subdominio...

Comment: añade al subirlo que error te dió?

Comment: También recuerda que tienes que modificar el archivo .htdocs y que hosting es?

Comment: Ya pude subirlo. Pero no me funcionan las rutas, me muestra el login principal, pero cuando ingreso el usuario y el password no me reconocen las rutas... sale error 404: The requested URL /login was not found on this server

Comment: Las rutas no me funcionan, ¿que tengo que hacer en el .htaccess?